# Laptop struggling to charge

Tags: laptop, asus-laptop, charging, charger

My 2 year old Asus Zenbook Ux305f has, very suddenly, started only charging when I hold the plug in the socket - it needs holding extremely tightly (I can't do it for very long without getting tired, sometimes it decides when I haven't even moved that it doesn't want to charge anymore), and the position I have to hold it in changes - I'm using a third party Lavonta charger that's done me a solid service for the last 8 months or so - before I shell out more money for a new charger, how likely is it that the fault will be with the laptop? I do have a care plan, but I can't get to the shop for a couple of days, and I need this laptop for my uni work.

Any help greatly appreciated!

Comment: Is there any visible damage to the socket or the plug?

Comment: None that I can see on either - the pin on the plug has a bit of a rock to it (I can move it ever so slightly back and forth with my finger), but it's been like that for months

Comment: Oh, I did drop the laptop just over a year ago on the corner where the socket is, and the casing is a little bent out of shape, but I've never had any problems as a result (don't know if that's relevant at all)

Answer (score 0):

"The socket": wall (AC mains) socket or DC adapter plug (usually round)?

- If the issue is the DC plug, then  most likely the connector *inside the laptop* broke loose from the PC board, or the wire to the plug is broken inside the insulation. To test this, borrow a similar supply to see if it charges.

  - If the borrowed supply works, then repair the break in the wire or put on a new DC connector - a five-minute job. You can find a specific [connector for your laptop](https://www.amazon.com/s/ref=nb_sb_noss?url=search-alias%3Delectronics&field-keywords=universal%20laptop%20connectors), or buy a [universal replacement supply](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0132ST35Y). Just be sure the voltage range includes that of the laptop and the current *equals or exceeds* it.
  - If the borrowed supply has the same behavior, i.e. you must press the connector, then likely the socket inside the laptop has broken loose from the PC board, or needs to be replaced. Again, this is a simple repair, but requires opening the case and resoldering or replacing the connector. If the laptop is **always** used on mains power, the power supply cord *could* be soldered directly to the PC board.
- If the issue is the mains plug, a replacement plug is available in most hardware stores... **be careful to wire correctly for the line, neutral and ground**, though.